# How to update a timestamp in SQL?

Tags: postgresql, carto, sql, timestamp

I've explored this forum fairly extensively trying to get answers as to why my SQL isn't working. I need help with the timestamp on a torque map. I've used the following formula, obviously changing the three variables, and it always comes up with an error message.

```
  UPDATE tablename set yearColumn = to_timestamp(yr_compl,'YYYY’)
```

My old column is a string and my new column is in date.

I'm a complete novice.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the query is totally perfect, except for something that seems a typo :-)

In your query, the last quote for 'YYYY' is not a regular quote, which might be raising a syntax error. Try fixing it instead:

```
UPDATE tablename SET yearColumn = to_timestamp(yr_compl,'YYYY')
```